# how can I delete added card list with braintree-web on ember.js

Tags: ember.js, braintree

I am using ember.js(2.0), braintree-web for payment.

Users can add their card information using Drop-in UI like below image.

[users card list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNF6d.png)

And users can see their card list in an account page like below image.

[added card list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmnPr.png)

If a user wants to delete their card lists, the lists can be deleted by click. How can I do? I think I can delete in deletePaymentMethod with token received.

Here is my payment-selector.js

```js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  ajax: Ember.inject.service(),
  session: Ember.inject.service(),

  createNewPaymentMethod: false,

  selectPaymentMethods: Ember.computed(function() {
    let array = this.get('paymentMethodsArray');
    array.pushObject({id:'newPaymentMethod',title:'Add new payment method'});
    return array;
  }),

  paymentMethodsArray:  Ember.computed.map('paymentMethods', function(item, index){
    return {id: item.get('token'), title: `${item.get('bin')}...${item.get('last4')}`};
  }),

  actions: {
    updatePaymentMethod: function(selection) {
      Ember.Logger.debug(selection);
      if (selection.id == 'newPaymentMethod') {
        this.set('createNewPaymentMethod', true);
      } else {
        this.set('createNewPaymentMethod', false);
        this.sendAction('onPaymentMethodSelection', {token:selection.id});
      }
    },

    processBraintreeNonce: function(nonce) {
      Ember.Logger.debug(nonce);
      const self = this;
      const authenticated = this.get('session.data.authenticated');
      this.get('ajax').request(`account/${authenticated.account.id}/payment_methods`,{
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
          nonce: nonce
        }
      }).then(function(response){
        Ember.Logger.debug(response);
        self.sendAction('onPaymentMethodSelection', response.data);
        self.set('hideBrainTreeSubmit', true);
      }).catch(function(reason){
        self.set('hideBrainTreeSubmit', false);
        Ember.Logger.debug(reason);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I sent a mail to Braintree support team. then I received a reply.
In conclusion, There is no way to delete card information on front-end. It can be done on server-side.

Below is a reply from Braintree support team

To delete a payment method, you’ll need to use one of the server-side SDK (available in Java, .Net, Node.js, PHP, Python, Ruby). The braintree-web library is a client SDK which only helps you collect the payment method information in exchange for a payment method nonce. You’ll still need to integrate server SDK to perform any action with the payment method nonce. What you would do here is create an AJAX call and send the token to your server and delete from there.